# EntityFramework and Spatial Search POINT inside POLYGON

Tags: linq, entity-framework-5, spatial

I have an entity called Shop which has a DBGeorgpraphy column called Position

A sample shop in the database has a Position value of POINT (145.034242 -37.825519)

I am trying to retrieve all shops that fall within a polygon.

```
var polygon = DbGeography.PolygonFromText(@"POLYGON((145.2898592378906 -37.66376896413059,
                                                     145.2898592378906 -37.93504877166811, 
                                                     144.7075838472656 -37.93504877166811, 
                                                     144.7075838472656 -37.66376896413059, 
                                                     145.2898592378906 -37.66376896413059))", 
                                                     4326);

var shops = db.Shops.Where(p => p.Position.Intersects(polygon));
```

I would expect the sample shop to be included in the results but it doesn't. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to construct the polygon in the opposite direction, i.e. anti-clockwise.

```
var polygon = DbGeography.PolygonFromText(@"POLYGON((145.2898592378906 -37.66376896413059,
                                                     144.7075838472656 -37.66376896413059,
                                                     144.7075838472656 -37.93504877166811,
                                                     145.2898592378906 -37.93504877166811, 
                                                     145.2898592378906 -37.66376896413059))", 
                                                     4326);
```

Comment: This certainly did the trick. Adding why it makes a difference would greatly improve this answer in my opinion.